# Is an order something transient or not

Tags: domain-driven-design, bounded-contexts

In my company (train company) there is a sort of battle going on over two viewpoints on something. Before going to deep into the problem I'm first going to explain the different domains we have in our landscape now.

*Product:* All product master data and their characteristics.
Think their name, their possible list of choices...

*Location:* All location master data that can be chosen, like stations, stops, etc.

*Quote:* To get a price for a specific choice of a product with their attributes.

*Order:* The order domain where you can make a positive order but also a negative one for reimbursements.

*Ticket:* This is essentially what you get from paying the order. Its the product but in the state that its at, when gotten by the customer.

## The problem

### Viewpoint PURPLE (I don't want to create bias)

When an order is transformed into all "tickets", we convert the order details, like price, into the ticket model. In order to make Order something we can *throw away*. Order is seen as something *transient*. Kind of like the bag you have in a supermarket. Its the goods inside the bag that matter. Not the bag itself.

When  a reimburse flow would start. You do not need to go to the order. You would have everything in the Ticket domain. So this means data from order will be duplicated to Ticket.

But not all, only the things that are relevant. Like price for example.

### Viewpoint YELLOW (I don't want to create bias)

You do the same as above but you do not store the price in Ticket domain. The ticket domain only consist of details that are relevant for the "ticket" to work. Price is not allowed in there cause its a thing of the order. When a reimburse flow would start, its allowed to go fetch those details from the order. Making order not something you can throw away as its having crucial data inside of it.

The benefit here is that Order is not "polluting" the Ticket with unnecessary data. But this is debatable. The example of the price is a good example.

I wish to know your ideas about these two viewpoints.

Comment: Does some order issue _multiple tickets_? If yes, do you reimburse each tickets or reimburse the order as a whole?

Comment: @f.nasim order can issue N tickets yes. You can reimburse the whole order or you can reimburse 1 ticket.   Reimbursing a whole order is a usecase we have, but one that will not be used often. You always reimburse 1 ticket..... as per analogy of amazon. or any big seller.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "Don't repeat yourself" when it comes to the business domain. The only thing that dictates the business domain is the business requirements. If the requirements state that the ticket should work independent of the order changes, then you have to duplicate things.

But in this case, the requirements are ***ambiguous***. There is no correct design using the currently specified requirements. *Building code based on assumptions is the #1 way of getting bad code*, since you most likely will have to do a redesign down the road.

You need to go back to the product owner and ask him about the difference between the Order and the Ticket.

For instance:

- What should happen to the ticket if the order is deleted?
- What happens to the order and/or ticket if the product price changes?
- What happens to a ticket if the order is reimbursed?

Go back, get better requirements and then start to design the application.

Comment: Our business is never delivering clear requirements. So we, the supplier should help them. Our architects are saying we need to avoid the need to have an order, the details should all be in the ticket. Just to save the extra hop, and to let ticket live Independant. You said there is no DRY when its about business domains. That makes a lot of sense... never saw it like that.  When a reimbursement would be starting, the best outcome would be that pretty much all info would be in ticket. And we dont need to extract the original orderline from order....

Comment: I tought i would get a clear answer that first thing is the best way to ho about it but this seems not the case, a domain is something that has its own business... thats why its seperated as a domain. Also when you put the orice in ticket and not let it be gotten from order, you remove a big dependemcy in order.... which is a good thing.